# How to use send_static_file in Flask gunicorn nginx setup?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I want to call send_static_file, that refers to a static html file, from my Flask application. The code works fine on localhost, but when I set it up with nxingx and  gunicorn I get an error:

> 404 URL Not Found error.

My flask app routes to:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .frontend import frontend

application = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

application.register_blueprint(frontend, url_prefix='/app')

@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "hello world" ------>>>>>THIS WORKS
    #return application.send_static_file('frontend/static/dist/index.html') ------>>>>>>>THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.34.18.48;
    error_log /var/www/appname/nginx_errorlog.log;
    access_log /var/www/appname/nginx_accesslog.log;

    root /var/www/appname;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

When I just return a string, the string is shown, but when I return a static file content, I get the error.

UPDATE 1:

Running flask in debug returns:

> - Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
>     (Press CTRL+C to quit)  * Restarting with stat  * Debugger is active!
> - Debugger pin code: XXX-XXX-XXX
>     127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2016 04:09:20] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
>     127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2016 04:09:29] "GET /app HTTP/1.0" 301 -
>     127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2016 04:09:29] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.0" 404 -

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is internally used by Flask. I would not suggest using this in this manner.

If you need to serve static files, I would suggest configuring Nginx to handle this for you. This is great in the case of having some parts of the site be very high-performance!

If you need to use Flask, look at [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory). This is probably what you need.

Comment: could you please explain a little more why you suggest not using send_static_file and why its not working with nginx?

Comment: I wouldn't use it because Nginx is more optimized to send static files. If you want to serve dynamic content with Flask you would use `render_template`. Also, send_static_file is a Flask internals thing: it is what it uses to serve files from the "static" directory.